# use ffmpeg as dll in c++ windows

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I need to import ffmpeg but I don't want to use it as static lib I want to dynamicly link it but I couldn't find a proper way to do it. I only found the source code from its site and the compiled .exe files. Is there a way for me to use it as dll? do ffmpeg.dll exist or should I compile it myself?

Comment: There isn't `ffmpeg.dll` but if you download `ffmpeg-release-full-shared.7z` (Gyan's) it comes with `libav***.dll` files that you could link in your project. You should be able to find a lot of info if you search for "how to use ffmpeg libav library in C++" to get a lot of info out there.

Comment: @kesh Thanks, it seems that I downloaded the non-shared version, this has everything I needed. One question though, there is a .a extension at the end of those .dll files, what does it mean and does it make any difference? I'm using premake5 build.

Comment: The actual DLLs are in the `bin` folder. I'm not familiar with `.dll.a` files I used `.def` or `.lib` files for linking (way back when I used it)